# Do NIMH batteries have a shelf life?

Tags: batteries, nimh

I have some 15 year old NIMH batteries which were not touched for 10 years.

I tried charging them with a peak charger and they didn't hold a charge. I'm wondering if they died via age or some other reason.

Comment: I've some that are about that old that I just unearthed and recharged to see how they did. Some of the brands were useless and didn't hold much of a charge. However, the *eneloop* batteries (except for one of them) all seem to be working pretty darned well. Here's [an example of their AAA datasheet](https://eneloop101.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/HR-4UTG.pdf). All of mine were stored together. So no differences in environment. But manufacturing quality probably matters as do storage environmentals, I expect.

Comment: If they measure zero volts, and zero resistance, they may have tiny metal whiskers that are shorting the cells. Sometimes you can charge up a capacitor to several volts and zap the cell to blow open the shorting conductors. Then they might accept a charge.